# Data not being passed from views.py to template

Tags: python, django

I'm passing a dictionary to views.py and I want to output data from it to the site page.

But instead I get pure html, no data.

views.py:

`

```
def index(request):
    data = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [37.62, 55.793676]
          },
          "properties": {
            "title": "«Легенды Москвы",
            "placeId": "moscow_legends",
            "detailsUrl": "static/Moscow_map/places/moscow_legends.json"
          }
        }
     ]
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=data)
```

`

index.html:

`

```
{{ data|json_script:"data-b" }}
<script id="data-b" type="application/json">

</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

there is no **data** key in your context...

```py
def index(request):
    geojson = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [37.62, 55.793676]
          },
          "properties": {
            "title": "«Легенды Москвы",
            "placeId": "moscow_legends",
            "detailsUrl": "static/Moscow_map/places/moscow_legends.json"
          }
        }
     ]
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={"data": geojson})
```

And your usage for json_script seems bad. Remove the **script** tag

```
{{ data|json_script:"data-b" }}
```

Comment: this did not help, the data is still not displayed on the page

Comment: Without more information, i do not know how more help you ? What is the html result ?